# Problemas al animar icono con la clase de Font Awesome en Font Awesome 6

Tags: html, css, angular, font-awesome

Estoy en angular 12 y al querer usar la clase fa-spin de **Font Awesome** en **Font Awesome 6** la animación no aparece, el icono si.

La etiqueta que intento usar es la siguiente:

```
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col fa-3x">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Se supone que con el fa-spin debería iniciar una animación de giro pero no sucede.

- Bajé el archivo y lo metí en los assets para trabajarlo en local. Desde el angular.json llamo el all.css y all.js

Comment: Incluye todos los elementos que consideres necesario para que cualquiera pueda reproducir tu escenario, de otro modo, estaríamos jugando al detective con un interrogatorio extenso. Saludos. :D

Comment: Simplemente te falta crear el `@keyframe fa-spin {} ` en tu CSS y ya está

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FontAwesome implementa el media query [`prefers-reduced-motion`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion)

> La función multimedia CSS de `prefers-reduced-motion` se utiliza para detectar si el usuario ha solicitado que el sistema minimice la cantidad de movimiento no esencial que utiliza.

El mismo esta definido así:

```
@media (prefers-reduced-motion:reduce) {
    .fa-beat,.fa-beat-fade,.fa-bounce,.fa-fade,.fa-flip,.fa-pulse,.fa-shake,.fa-spin,.fa-spin-pulse {
        -webkit-animation-delay: -1ms;
        animation-delay: -1ms;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1ms;
        animation-duration: 1ms;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        transition-delay: 0s;
        transition-duration: 0s
    }
}
```

Al utilizar `reduce`

> Indica que el usuario ha notificado al sistema que prefiere una interfaz que elimine o reemplace los tipos de animación basada en movimiento que provocan molestias para las personas con trastornos del movimiento vestibular.

Y si analizamos la regla podemos ver que la animación se realiza 1 sola vez e inicia antes de que la podamos ver.

## Solución:

Existen 2 opciones:

1. Borrar dicha implementación del archivo CSS
2. Pisarla

#### Ejemplo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<style>
@media (prefers-reduced-motion:reduce) {
  .fa-beat,.fa-beat-fade,.fa-bounce,.fa-fade,.fa-flip,.fa-pulse,.fa-shake,.fa-spin,.fa-spin-pulse {
    -webkit-animation-delay: var(--fa-animation-delay, 0);
    animation-delay: var(--fa-animation-delay, 0);
    -webkit-animation-duration: var(--fa-animation-duration, 2s);
    animation-duration: var(--fa-animation-duration, 2s);
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: var(--fa-animation-iteration-count, infinite);
    animation-iteration-count: var(--fa-animation-iteration-count, infinite);
  }
}
</style>

<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col fa-3x">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me decidí por la segunda forma y funciono. Aun así no logré entender muy bien el problema que tiene esa @media. Sé que se quitan 2 propiedades pero no entiendo el conflicto real.

Comment: @CarlosEscobar, actualice mi respuesta. Espero que ahora se entienda mejor porque no se ve la animación.